Please, help identify a sci-fi movie where the sun "burns" people
Since I was a kid, I remember a film I cannot identify in which for some reason (maybe a really big sun flare), people dies in their houses and (of course) streets. People just dissolves into a dust shape of what they were when alive.
I remember a scene where some people (that I don't know exactly where they were before) come back to some house (probably their house) and see the ashes of two people dead lying over their bed. That struck me, but I really cannot remember the film name, and I don't know how to search for it.
Any hints? My first search result is "The Core", but this one is from 2003. The one I remember may be around the 70's.

Sounds like it might be Night of the Comet.

Well, yes, it might be, thanks!... Although I don't remember any cheerleaders :)

Gotcha. The one girl wore a cheerleader outfit at the beginning. I think that was a short lived outfit ... as they stormed Macy's or some such to get some new outfits ... since everyone else was dead, why not! :D

It sounds like Where Have All The People Gone?, a 1974 TV movie with Peter Graves.  I've never seen it, but it is indeed from the 70s, and the description says that in it, people turn to dust as a result of an extremely strong solar flare.  Currently, someone has put the movie on YouTube, so you coud watch it and see if it's the one you remember.
